# Detecting received signal strength (RSS) of wifi devices

Tags: java, wireless

I am currently working on an application that should be able to detect wifi devices in the area. I have been successful in detecting these devices using Kismet, which lets me find all APs and clients (associated or not) in the region. However, besides detecting these devices, I also wish to know their signal strength to try and pinpoint their position at a given time. The only way I seem to be able to monitor this is using the kismet_client (which I do not want) and in real time it shows me the current power levels.

Since I need to feed this data to an event manager (in Java) which will be running in an automated fashion I would need some way to capture it, other than looking at the screen... (for example, if something triggers an event near a sensor, I would like to know which device it was, assuming it was the closest one to trigger it, and the closest one having the highest signal strength).

Does anyone know of a way to log/capture the latest RSS value seen using kismet_server only?

Thank you.

ps. if not using Kismet, please suggest some other tool to use in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently doing this by checking the kismet netxml log file periodically. This log file presents signal information under the "snr-info" tag. To retrieve these values I am using the java SAX parser. Don't know if this is the most efficient way, but seems to be working so far.

Comment: There probably is a better way.  The logs are "pushed" asynchronously, whereas you should be able to "pull" the data when YOU want/need it.  The hardware device probably has electrically erasable programmable memory (EEPROM) that stores that data--you need to find out how to access it.  Note that the signal power value likely is not that accurate, does not address noise/distortion/etc. issues, is possibly updated periodically, could have a limited number of EEPROM read/write cycles, and might have other issues--hopefully the manufacturer has good docs/support (that can be an issue).